# Class using resource pointer- Resource class with copy constructor and copy assignment operator

Tags: c++

I have created two simple classes: `resource` and `container`. below is the full code. actually container keeps resources. and in the beganing it will get all the resources and store them in datalist of resources. The other function is simply prints out all the resources in container. Please review my code and see if its ok just review it and let me know what are the wrongs and rights in the code, thanks

```
////
// Created by noone on 18/8/21.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#define Max 10
class resource{
private:
public:
    int id;
    char name[10];

    resource(int id,char name1[10]):id(id)
    {

        std::memcpy(name,name1,Max);
    }
    resource& operator= (const resource& arr2){
        if (this == &arr2){ return *this; } //make sure you aren't self-assigning
        //same as copy constructor from here
        id=arr2.id;
        std::memcpy(name,arr2.name,Max);
        return *this;
    }


};
class container
{
public:
    container(resource *new_resource,int i)
    {
            size=0;
            size=i;
            datalist=(resource *)malloc(sizeof(resource)*i);
            for(int x=0;x<i;x++)
            {
                datalist[x].id=new_resource[x].id;
                std::memcpy(datalist[x].name,new_resource[x].name,std::strlen(new_resource[x].name));

            }


    }
    void print_all_resources()
    {
        std::cout<< "total "<<size<<" resources found"<<std::endl;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            std::cout<<"Printintg first resource"<<i+1<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<datalist[i].name << " | "<< datalist[i].id<<std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    resource *datalist;
    int size;
};

int main()
{
    resource resource1(10,"abc");
    resource resource2(20,"xyz");
    resource r[]={resource2,resource1};

    container c(r,2);
    c.print_all_resources();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used a `string`, you would not need to write the `operator=` at all.  You would not need the copy constructor either, which is missing from your code.

You ask

> can u [sic] show it my resource constructor expect two parameters if I use `new` then how to call the constructor of resource with two parameters? `datalist=new resource[i];` <<---error , resource constructor expects two parameter:`id`,`name1` what do u say about this?

*If* you needed to use `new`, you would pass the arguments like this:
`resource* p = new resource(name,id);`

However, I think what you really want here is just a `vector<resource>`.  You don't need to write a `container` class that stores a dynamically allocated array and its size — there are containers ready available in the standard library.

Here is my take on it:

- there is no `Max`.

```
struct resource {
   std::string name;
   int id;
   };

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const resource& res);  // write this.
```

You *could* write `using resource_container = std::vector<resource>;` but your code can use any kind of container freely with `resource`, and algorithms don't care which container you used, so this is not a type to be defined at all.

Note that `resource` doesn't need the copy constructor, destructor, or assignment operator, since the `string` already takes care of itself properly.  There is *no* special housekeeping needed:  this is the **rule of zero**.

I don't need a constructor, either.  Since all the data members are public, you can just use the aggregate initializer.  This is OK since this is, in fact, a simple bag of data, with no special checking that the values are in agreement or anything like that — any values for the individual fields will work.

Note that with a `vector` you don't call `new` at all.  You just `push_back`.

I think the problem you were asking about is that making an array requires a default constructor.  Your use of `malloc` avoids the issue but does not fix anything:  creating a "blank" array of `n` resources leaves them uninitialized in your code, or default initialized in fixed code, but those array elements are not really ready to use, and you need to assign over them.  With the `vector` you don't have an array of `n` items in some blank state; you *don't* have an item at all until you are ready to add it!  See the difference?  With a `vector`, at no time do you have extra unused elements at the end of the array; they are all valid values.

```
vector<resource> Ct;
Ct.push_back({"name",27});
Ct.puch_back({"another_with_long_name",42});
```

You could also create a vector all at once:

```
vector<resource> Container2 {
   {"name",27}, {"another_with_long_name",42}
};
```

But if you don't plan on adding more entries afterwards, you don't even need a `vector`.  A plain array will do.  As you have in the original for `r`, but without re-copying the values, and even doing it all at compile-time for zero run-time overhead!

```
constexpr resource r[] {
   {"name",27}, {"another_with_long_name",42}
};
```

Notice how this is exactly the same as for the `vector` example.

You want a function ready-made for printing the entire collection?
Note that it doesn't matter what kind of container you use — this works for the plain array, and `vector`, and many others.

```
template <typename R>
void print_all_resources (const R& collection)
{
    for (auto& r : collection) {
    std::cout << r.name << " | "<< r.id << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: `If you needed to use new, you would pass the arguments like this:
resource* p = new resource(name,id)` I do not want single object contained in p array. What I wanted was multiple resources to be accessed by p +i where i is index of a   resource in p array

Comment: The point I am using not using string and vector so I can create my own container instead of relying on stl containers. Although I like to use the iterator from stl embedded in my container class as struct

Comment: resource* p = new resource(name,id)` I do not want single object contained in p array. What I wanted was multiple resources to be accessed by p +i where i is index of a   resource in p array. Need to allocate all received resources and allocate by calling resource constructor so allocate array of sizes i.of resources.

Comment: @user786 I explained this in my Answer, "making an array requires a default constructor...."

Comment: Ok. Can u please tell can i attach my stl iterator with my  container class

Comment: *Do not* write your own container class.  That is a highly advanced subject and you are not fully understanding containers yet; learn to _use_ them first.  There are Boost libraries that help you write iterators for your own containers.  But I really can't parse the sentence "can i [sic] attach my stl iterator with my container class [?]"  You can certainly use iterators with a plain array, `vector`, etc. of `resource`.  The built-in ranged `for` loop is defined in terms of iterators, `begin` and `end`.

Comment: please understand I will write my own container class so please just give me a good link or something or what help resource on internet I can use. u can guide on this if u can. I think I love 3 rule for resources in T template its so customizable. This is the only reason to ran away from .net and C# so try learning linux and C C++. so if u may just give me a starting point I will do my best

Comment: If you are going to write a container class, it should be a _container_, period.  That is, not specific to one type of element, but templated.  The container has the responsibility for holding the multiple values, and is not specific to the type of value.  You need to understand containers better before you have any hope of writing one: see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container for an overview.

Comment: You can also see [Boost.Container](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/container.html) for containers that are not in `std` and containers that are enhanced (relative to older standards anyway).  Here you can see some valid reasons for making a container implementation: it does something that the `std` containers do not.  What does your container need to do that's not satisfied by `vector`?

Comment: `If you are going to write a container class, it should be a container, period. That is, not specific to one type of element, but templated. The container has the responsibility for holding the multiple values, and is not specific to the type of value` is there a repository on github for already implemented container. That can be easy to understand the link is just giving basic info while may be important I need to see it first

Comment: How about this I think with some efforts not too much I can convert it to tor type T class data https://github.com/bkthomps/Containers/blob/master/src/vector.c

Comment: That bkthomps code is not C++ and has nothing to do with C++ containers.  You need to explicitly construct and destruct elements, and maintain un-constructed memory between the current length and the capacity.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a weird mix of C and C++. It's essentially C with classes (which is to say, it's not very good C++ code).

---

1. Use `constexpr` instead of `#define` to define constants. `constexpr` retains type information.
2. Use `std::string` instead of a char array.
3. Implement the rule of [0-3-5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Although you have defined a copy assignment operator for `resource`, you haven't defined a copy constructor, or any move constructors/assignment operators. You also haven't defined any constructors/assignment operators for `container`.
4. Instead of manually managing memory through `malloc`, consider using  `std::vector`. It does all the heavy lifting for you and is safer.
5. Even if you want to avoid `std::vector` and manage memory yourself (to learn), you should use `new` and `delete` instead of `malloc` and `free`.
6. Speaking of `free`, I don't see it. You're leaking memory since you don't deallocate memory that you allocated through `malloc`. Ideally, you'd want to create a destructor that would call `free` when the `container` object goes out of scope (gets destroyed). This is a very important concept in C++: [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization (RAII)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii)
7. Instead of defining a method called `print_all_resources`, a more idiomatic approach would be to overload `operator<<`.
8. Instead of creating a temporary array and passing it to the `container` constructor, you can use initializer list to pass an arbitrary amount of `resource`s to the constructor.

   ```
   container(std::initializer_list<resource> rsc)
   {
      resources.insert(resources.end(), rsc);
   }
    private:
       std::vector<resource> resources;
   ```

   and call it like this:

   ```
   resource r1;
   resource r2;
   container c({r1, r2});
   ```
9. Prefer to use `std::copy` over `memcpy`.